# Python Dataframe: Get name of the day from number?

Tags: python, dataframe, calendar

I have `df` with a column `number`. I'm trying to get day name based on value?
df

```
            number      
    0       4           
    1       6            
    2       3            
    3       2           
    4       0
```

As per python calendar:

```
    import calendar
    list(calendar.day_name)

    ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

expected output

```
            number      day_name
    0       4           Friday
    1       6           Sunday
    2       3           Thursday
    3       2           Wednesday
    4       0           Monday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply` method on the `number` column of the dataframe. Details of the `apply` method can be found in the [Pandas official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
import calendar
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame({"number":[4,6,3,2,0]})
days = list(calendar.day_name)
data['day_name'] = data['number'].apply(lambda x: days[x])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   number   day_name
0       4     Friday
1       6     Sunday
2       3   Thursday
3       2  Wednesday
4       0     Monday
```